# gmaps4rails v2 and MarkerClusterer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, markerclusterer, gmaps4rails2

I'm using gmaps4rails V2 and I have do re-define the MarkerClusterer default behaviour changing the grid size. How can i accomplish my goal?

Thanks 
Claudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just found out the answer myself:

```
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", { markers: { clusterer: {gridSize: 30, maxZoom: 15} } })
```

Happy mapping :-)

Answer (score 0):

Claudio look up [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers#wiki-options)

The `clusterer_gridSize` is available to chage

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it in version 2 of this gem. Could you please show me an example?